# Conectar el ONT a PC con Windows Server

Tags: windows

Soy inciado en redes, estoy estudiando en estos momentos. Tengo un PC con Windows Server 22. Quiero conectar el ONT al PC (con la Ethernet que lleva la placa base, 1000). Tengo los datos PPPoE que me ha facilitado el operador DIGI. Estoy haciendo la conexión telefónica pero me sale siempre error 651. He intentado hacer la misma conexión con un PC con Windows 10 Pro y el resultado es el mismo. Creo que queda descartado que el tipo de SO sea el problema, ¿no? ¿A qué se puede deber mi problema? ¿Es por el puerto Ethernet? de la placa que no sea compatible, por algún motivo, con el PPPoE?